# Oracle: FK on union of two tables?

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

I have a situation which (simplified) looks like this:

- Table UNITS has a PK on UNITS.NAME. (unit name, varchar(12))
- Table DEPTS has a PK on DEPTS.NAME. (dept name, varchar(12))
- I want to create a table with column `UNIT_NAME_OR_DEPT_NAME`, with the
  requirement that data in this column must be either a valid unit
  name or a valid department name.

I tried adding two FK constraints, but found this gave me the
intersection rather than the union of the two tables.

```
 CONSTRAINT FOO_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(NAME) REFERENCES UNITS(NAME) ENABLE,
 CONSTRAINT FOO_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(NAME) REFERENCES DEPTS(NAME) ENABLE,
```

How can I create a FK or other constraint that would me to reference
the union of two tables?

Comment: I am glad I came across this question because I have a use case that mirrors this, but I came to a realization that even though a solution can work, it has so much moving parts that in my case would cause more problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with two hidden columns `units_fk` and `dept_fk` with proper FK constraints and an additionnal `CHECK CONSTRAINT`, for example if the pseudo-column is mandatory:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_units_dept_fk CHECK 
    (units_fk IS NULL AND dept_fk IS NOT NULL)
 OR (units_fk IS NOT NULL AND dept_fk IS NULL)
```

You could then add a shadow column in a view

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS 
SELECT col1,...coln, nvl(units_fk, dept_fk) as UNIT_NAME_OR_DEPT_NAME
  FROM my_table
```

You could deal with updates of the pseudo-column either with procedures (my choice) or with `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`.

Comment: Thanks... btw, love your icon.  check my profile and you'll see why. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want one column to point at two different tables? Why not two different columns in a Many:Many relationship? You will probably have to use a trigger to check that at least one is not null before allowing an insert.

Comment: You shouldn't use a single column to hold two different types of data. What happens if you get a unit with the same name as a department ? If they can't then you have an entity that has name as a primary key/candidate key and an attribute indicating whether it is a unit or department, and THAT should be the parent table.

Comment: You can use a simple check constraint to enforce that only one column has a value set. And you could use a view with a NVL(UNIT,DEPT) if, for any reason you did want to see them as a single column.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do this:

Have a sequence called "MasterKey"  (or whatever).

Have a third table called "SequencesUsed" or something which would have only a single column - the used values from MasterKey.  When a new record is created in your unit and department tables, trigger a new record in the sequencesUsed table and put the value generated iin the appropriate table as a foriegn key.

Your new table would have a field called "dept_or_unit_id" that have theSequencesUsed table as it's foreign key.

So something like this:

MasterKey: column:  ID  values:  1, 2, 3, 4, 
Unit:  column: name, masterkey values: foo, 1; bar, 3; 
Dept:  column: name, masterkey. values: one, 2; star, 4;
NewTable:  column: masterkey values: 1, 2, 3, 4

there's probably a way to improve this a bit, depending on how you are using the data, but it seems like joins would be a lot easier later than if you had one field point at two places.